# Remove Browser Window toolbar and menubar without window.open?

Tags: javascript, toolbar, menubar, window.open

This may be an oddball request, but I was curious if there was any way to remove browser window's menubar and toolbar without using the window.open?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not anymore. If you had a secured applet running on the page, or flash, you might be able to hijack the user's system to get it done, but both are sketchy at best.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! That makes sense, and puts an end to my curiosity.